# How to update JSONObject by key value?

Tags: java, json

I have this JSONFile

```
{"PostsDetails":[
      {
    "pageInfo": {
    "pagePic": "http://example.com/abc.jpg",
    "pageName": "abc"
    },
  "id": 1,
  "posts": [
    {
      "likesCount": "2",
      "nameOfPersonWhoPosted": "Jane Doe",
      "post_id": "0987654321_123456789012",
      "timeOfPost": "0987654321",
      "actor_id": "0987654321",
      "message": "Can't wait to see it!",
      "picOfPersonWhoPosted": "http://example.com/abc.jpg"
    }
   ]
 }
]}
```

And I have this method to update by id and write the JSONObject to file. How I can update the object by id? I have no idea on how I can do it. I tried to remove the old object from the file then put the new object in the file but I don't want it to be appended on the last part of the file.

The "JSONObject post" on the parameter has the updated values of the object.

```
public Message updatePost(long id, JSONObject post) {

    Message message = new Message("Failed", false);
    if (!post.isEmpty()) {
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = fileUtil2.getFileJSONObject();
            JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("PostsDetails");

            Iterator itr = arr.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) itr.next();
                if (obj.get("id").equals(id)) {
                   //Not sure what to put here
                }

                if(fileUtil2.writeToFile(jsonObject)){
                    message.setMessage("Contact Updated.");
                    message.setStatus(true);
                }
                else{
                    message.setMessage("An error occured.");
                    message.setStatus(false);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
     return message;
}
```

Comment: To use JSon as a persistence format you have to use more than a file system. Take a look at MongoDb or other document oriented database (mostly nosql)

Comment: @Aubin Its my school assignment and they are requiring us to use file system.

Comment: If you must use only one file, you should load the entire file, split it into documents indexed by id (using a Map<String, JSONObject>), replace the entry by Map.put( id, post) and rewrite the entire file.